# Python error "TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am getting an error from this python code

```
def read_lines():
    user_entries = []
    contin = True
    while contin == True:
        user_input = input(str("Enter string or just press enter to finish: "))
        user_entries.append(user_input)
        if len(user_input) == 0:
            contin = False
    print(user_entries)

lines = read_lines()
print(lines)
ci = o
contin = True
while contin:
    if ci == len(lines):
        contin = False
    else:
        line = lines(ci, ci + 1)
        ci = ci + 1
        print(ci, line)
```

I then get this error...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 8 in <module>
    if ci == len(lines):
Type Error: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

I'm not quite sure why i get this error.  When it executes the line print(lines) it returns None.  That's probably the issue but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: the function you defined `read_lines()` does not return anything to `lines` so it is **None**.

Comment: Don't forget to mark any of the answers as [answered](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwjf__iKnpnTAhXky4MKHeloBR8QFggZMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmeta.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions%2F5234%2Fhow-does-accepting-an-answer-work&usg=AFQjCNE2e2orpogybVZU_sdJD6evWbT5Fw&bvm=bv.152174688,d.amc&cad=rja)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you defined `read_lines()` does not return anything to `lines` so it is **None**.

In your function add return after printing.

```
return user_entries
```

Also you need do changes in your code such as `line = lines(ci, ci + 1)`

`lines` is a list: it's not callable.

`ci = 0` instead of `ci = o`

Please remove the typos, errors and try again. Should work.

Answer (score 1):

Your function `read_lines` doesn't return anything

```
def read_lines():
    user_entries = []
    contin = True
    while contin == True:
        user_input = input(str("Enter string or just press enter to finish: "))
        user_entries.append(user_input)
        if len(user_input) == 0:
            contin = False
    print(user_entries) # this prints user_entries but doesn't return it
```

Add a `return user_entries` to your function after the call to `print` and your code should work

Answer (score 0):

**I have executed this code using python 2.7**

-- > function `read_lines()` does not return anything that is one thing.

but inside the while loop, instead of using :

```
user_input = input(str("Enter string or just press enter to finish: "))
```

Use :

```
user_input = raw_input("Enter string or just press enter to finish: ")
```

So you will not have next errors. ;)